# How to install Linux from live to normal on the same drive?

Tags: fedora, partition, system-installation

My PC has 2 HDs (`sda`, `sdb`) And I also have a 1TB hard drive which is connected by USB (`sdc`)
I installed a live Linux distro (Fedora) on one of the partitions on `sdc`.

It works nice but after I reboot all my created data on this live system is gone. (I guess the live version is not persistent)
I would like to install Fedora now on that 1TB drive so it is not more a "live" distro and I can use it as a normal OS.

If I try this, The installer gets only my "real" hard drives (`sda`, `sdb`) which are installed in my PC (not by USB)
Any idea how to install Linux from `sdc` to `sdc`? (e.g. `sdc1` to `sdc2`)

Comment: What Linux distribution and version?

Comment: @fpmurphy1  Fedora 23

Comment: OK, I have a solution. Connect the USB HD and install it from a small USB stick. Now I can select the USB HD. :)